# Load JSON data with useMemo

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-usememo

In the following [line](https://github.com/gopinav/React-Table-Tutorials/blob/1709c8664ed0c030b7ca1fc5a2519cf386bcf5e8/react-table-demo/src/components/BasicTable.js#L9):

it loads the json data using `useMemo`

```
import MOCK_DATA from './MOCK_DATA.json'
const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])
```

As it's mentioned in [ReactTable](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start) that
`It's important that we're using React.useMemo here to ensure that our data isn't recreated on every render.`

My question is will the import statement in reactjs be triggered each time the js file is executed (and that makes `useMemo` necessary)? If yes, is there a source that mentioned that?